# How to add extra column to Order Entity in Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am working on an assignment to add some extra columns to Order entity when order save into database. But it's using database table name _SitecoreCommerce.SharedEnviornment table and data store in db like given below:

[image]

Where to add a new column in this scenario? Can we solve this by creating a new plugin for order customization? If yes then how to define columns and assign the values while order capturing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 uses a sort-of NOSQL approach to data, so what you see in SQL Server is a JSON-serialized representation of your order.

You can add extra information to an order by adding a new Component to an order.

Kelly Heard from Sitecore has a blogpost (https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/the_commerce_experience/posts/simple-commerce-plugin) on how to extend a line item which you can easily extend to extending an order.

If you need help, let me know.

Comment: Do we have any way for extending commerce reports?

Comment: Which reports do you mean?